# Load custom starter properties files based on profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

With spring boot v2.3.4 I could use `ConfigFileApplicationListener` to load properties files from my custom starters by writing a environment post processor like

```
public class StarterEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    private final ConfigFileApplicationListener environmentPostProcessor = new ConfigFileApplicationListener();

    public StarterEnvironmentPostProcessor(String name) {
        environmentPostProcessor.setSearchNames(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        environmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(environment, application);
    }
}
```

And then from each starter I could subclass this environment post processor like

```
public class MyStarterEnvironmentPostProcessor extends StarterEnvironmentPostProcessor {

    public MyStarterEnvironmentPostProcessor() {
        super("my-starter");
    }
}
```

This would result in properties being loaded appropriately i.e. if I ran the application that consumes this starter, with profile `dev`, then properties would be loaded from `my-starter.properties`, `my-starter-dev.properties`, `application.properties` and `application-dev.properties`, where the first two come from the starter and the last 2 come from the consuming project.

`ConfigFileApplicationListener` has been removed in spring boot v3.0.
The deprecation warning on the class suggests to use `ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor` instead.

After debugging I found that `StandardConfigDataLocationResolver` is used to resolve the properties files to be loaded.
It constructs config file names like

```
String[] configNames = binder.bind(CONFIG_NAME_PROPERTY, String[].class).orElse(DEFAULT_CONFIG_NAMES);
```

meaning there isn't a way for me to inject `my-starter` config name here.
I do not want the project that consumes the custom starters (there are multiple custom starters) to be aware of the config locations.
Rather I want the auto configured custom starters to be responsible for loading the appropriate properties.

How can I achieve this in spring boot v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

We do the same currently by using a application-custom.yml in our lib and in the yml-file we seperate in default dev and so on...

When you then activate the custom profile with spring.profiles.include in your main app spring picks up the applicaiton-custom.yml in your dependency

Comment: I guess that is one way to do it. But I'd rather have different properties files for different profiles/envs than sections in the same file.

Comment: I see mhh might work with this approach and profile groups then maby @RahulSharma

Comment: That does not work for me i checked it. What could work is spring.config.import in the application-custom.yml and spring.config.activate-on-profile.

So for dev:
spring:
    config:
         activate-on-profile: dev
         import: application-custom-dev.yml